# Python is NOT getting the path of the installation directory of Anaconda?

Tags: python, windows-8.1, spyder

I am trying to use the package unicodecsv and have installed anaconda already on my system.
I did following

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xy>conda install unicodecsv
Fetching package metadata: ....
Solving package specifications: ........................
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at C:\*********\Anaconda3:
#
unicodecsv                0.14.1                   py35_0
```

Why I am still not being able to import unicodecsv in my python editor?

Comment: anaconda install python and all its extras in its own folder, so you probably has right now 2 instances of python in your computer the old one and the anaconda one, check in the anaconda folder and you will see yours package in there, to avoid confusion remove the old one...

Comment: @Copperfield which one  to delete I got Python 27 and Python34 in my C: drive?

Comment: delete the python in the folder C:\Python27  and/or only use the python in the folder C:\*********\Anaconda3

Comment: I also install anaconda without removing my other python and just in case I modify my global PATH variable removing all references to C:\Python 27 and C:\Python 35 and instead put in its place the references to C:\Anaconda3 from my local PATH, making it my default python and with that I can use normally all its cool stuff